# Unspecified return values

Tags: c, return, return-value

With respect to return values:

```
func()
{
  while(1)
  {
    /* do stuff here */
    if(error1) exit(0);
    if(error2) break;
  }       
  /* no return statement anywhere in func() */
}
```

but the caller checks the return code of func()

```
if(func()) {/* error handling */}
```

what'd nice would be someone to confirm that the return value of `func()` does not default to anything and is junk. And that this is true for all these:

- `void func()`
- `int func()`, which is not featuring a return statement at all, or with a plain `return;`.
- `func()`, unspecified return type, which i understand defaults to returning int.

thanks..

Comment: Also note that defining or declaring a function in C with no listed arguments means the arguments are unspecified as well. If a function should take no arguments, it must explicitly be defined/declared taking an argument of `void`.

Comment: thanks @JoachimPileborg, i was actually emitting stuff there to make my point but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This answer applies to C89 (and earlier versions).

`void func()`  specifies a functions that doesn't return a value. In this case `if (func())` should result in a compile error.

`int func()` and `func()` are equivalent and return an integer value.
If no value is provided by a return statement the result is undefined, and the compiler issues a warning if the warning level is high enough.
In practice, most compilers will generate code that returns whatever is in the register or memory position used for the return value.

Comment: -1, implicit int is not valid C, it has been removed from the standard.

Comment: Thanks, added a note on that.

Comment: "the result is undefined" - to be precise *behavior* is undefined if "value of the function call is used by the caller". So it's not just "could be any integer, don't know which", it's "could crash". I'm not sure what calling convention would actually produce a crash, though.

Comment: @Steve. Poor choice of words on my part. You are absolutely right, whatever the program does, it doesn't break the C specification. If I ever write a C compiler, I'll add easter eggs for every undefined behaviour invoked. I mean, if you are going to fail, why not do it in style?

Answer (score 2):

The return value of a function is *generally* returned by the first register of the processor, e.g. EAX for x86 based or r0 for ARM based processor. It is compiler specific, but that is more or less standard.

e.g.`return 10;` in C will get translated to

```
mov eax 10 ; pseudo code
ret        ; pseudo code
```

in assembly for x86 based processor.

& While checking the return value, it will just check the eax register. Whatever is contained in that register is considered as return value by caller.

SO... If you return without a value (simple `return;`) or it's a void function, whatever value is contained in EAX just before `ret` statement in assembly, is taken as return value by the caller.

For `ARM` based processor, replace `EAX` by `r0` in above answer. :-)

I used this fact as a hack for below function ;-)

```
void* getStackTop(){
   asm("mov eax esp");
}
```

---

To check how exactly it works while translating from C to ASM, write a simple code as below:

```
int testfn(int unused){
   int unused2=unused; // Check how input is passed
   return 10;          // Check how output is returned
}
```

& then compile it with `gcc -S`. (or with your compiler with some flag that will generate only assembly.)

---

I am not sure how it returns float/struct values. *Probably* it returns a pointer to struct & entire returned struct is memcpy'ed under the hood, while translating to asm. Someone may rectify :-)

Comment: You are merely describing one of many possible undefined behaviors. It isn't really relevant in this case, since the code posted isn't valid C.

Comment: This answer was consistent with common compilers, like gcc/visual studio etc. However, it may be different on some compilers. Plus many compilers, including gcc _allow_ some additions/relaxations to **standard** C. At least on gcc, it would give only warning, if you omit return type & it will assume `int` : `warning: return type defaults to int [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: But there are numerous other CPU architectures where your answer doesn't apply. And for each such architecture, there are various different compilers, with different calling conventions.

Comment: As for GCC, I believe it is incorrect in giving a warning, I think it should give an error. Also note that GCC only gives this warning if you compile the code as C with -std=c99. If you compile it as "non-standard GNU goo", then you don't get a warning, at least not in GCC 4.6.2.

Comment: @Lundin: if you believe it should give an error then you should compile with `-pedantic-errors`. A warning is sufficient to conform to the standard, but I don't know whether you consider mere conformance to be sufficient to avoid the label "incorrect". It's inconvenient, in the sense that the kind of person who uses mostly default options and ships code that compiles with warnings probably doesn't realise when those warnings are telling them that their code isn't valid C99, and hence ships dodgy code even with `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted in not valid C code, since the C99 standard.

If you are using an obsolete compiler that implements the C90 standard, it would compile and the default type would then be int. I believe omitting the return statement from such a function would result in undefined behavior, though I can't cite the C90 standard.

Comment: "an obsolete compiler" -- for example gcc. Or clang, with suitable command line options. Or MSVC. It's not really an issue of what the compiler implements, so much as what language the code is written in. If it's written in C89 then you might need a C89 compiler to build it, and even if it happens to also be valid C99, for the sake of caution it's often easier to compile it as C89 than to figure out whether its meaning in C99 is the same as its meaning in C89.